# i have API key but when i put it in my android studio to return me list its return me but nothing and i can sad that its return me json

Tags: android

```
public class GetPlaceSearchTask extends AsyncTask<String , Void ,String> 
{
    private Context context;
private ProgressDialog dialog;
public static final String SEND_RESULT_SEARCH_BROADCAST_FROM_TASK = "send_result_search";


private String API_LOCATION = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/" +
        "json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=restaurant&name=cruise&key=";


public GetPlaceSearchTask(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}


protected void onPreExecute() {
    if (context != null) {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setTitle("Downloading");
        dialog.show();
    }
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        URL url = new URL(String.format(API_LOCATION, params[0], params[1]));
        connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            return null;
        }
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (connection != null) {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
    if (reader != null) {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if (dialog != null) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(SEND_RESULT_SEARCH_BROADCAST_FROM_TASK);
    intent.putExtra("result_search", result);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
}



public static class GetPlaceSearchTextTask extends AsyncTask<String , Void , String>{

    private String API_TEXT = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/" +
            "json?query=%1$s&location=[%2$s,%3$s]&radius=5000&key=";

    public static final String SEND_BROADCAST_RESULT_TEXT_FROM_TASK = "sand_text_result";

    private Context context;

    private ProgressDialog dialog ;

    public GetPlaceSearchTextTask(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        if (context != null) {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            dialog.setTitle("Downloading");
            dialog.show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder() ;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(API_TEXT + params[0] + params[1] + params[2]) ;
            connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())) ;
            String line;
            while ((line=reader.readLine())!= null){
                builder.append(line);
            }`enter code here`
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (connection!=null)
            connection.disconnect();
        if (reader!=null)
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result_text) {
        if (dialog!=null){
            dialog.dismiss();
        }`enter code here`
        Intent intent = new Intent(SEND_BROADCAST_RESULT_TEXT_FROM_TASK);
        intent.putExtra("text" , result_text);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: please HELP ME SOLVE IT

Comment: can somebody tall me what the problem with my code